# $G$ cocycle split and trivialized to a coboundary in $J$, given a group homomorphism $J \overset{r}{\rightarrow} G$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gr.group-theory, group-cohomology, spectral-sequences, quantum-field-theory

Consider a generic nontrivial 3-cocycle $\omega_3^G(g_1,g_2,g_3) \in H^3(G,U(1))$ in the cohomology group of $G$ with $U(1)=\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ coefficient. In otherwords, here the 3-cocycle $\omega_3^G$ is a complex $U(1)=\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ function with the norm $|\omega_3^G|=1$ but with a $U(1)$ complex phase satisfying the cocycle condition.

We like to ask how can we trivialize (or split) the 3-cocycle $\omega_3(g_1,g_2,g_3)$ of $G$ into 3-coboundary if we lift $G$ into a larger group $J$, and given that we know the group homomorphism $r$:
$$J \overset{r}{\rightarrow} G,$$
so that
$$\omega_3^J(j_1,j_2,j_3)=\omega_3^G(r(j_1),r(j_2),r(j_3))=\omega_3^G(g_1,g_2,g_3) \text{ is trivial in  }  H^3(J,U(1)).$$
Namely $\omega_3^G(r(j_1),r(j_2),r(j_3))$ becomes a 3-coboundary in $H^3(J,U(1))$ for the cohomology group of $J$, but $\omega_3^G(g_1,g_2,g_3)$ originally wass not a 3-coboundary but was a 3-cocycle for the cohomology group of $G$. Namely, we can explicitly write 
$$
\omega_3^G(g_1,g_2,g_3)=\omega_3^G(r(j_1),r(j_2),r(j_3))=
\frac{\beta_2^J(j_2,\; j_3)\beta_2^J(j_1,\; j_2\cdot j_3)}{\beta_2^J(j_1 \cdot  j_2,\; j_3) \beta_2^J(j_1,\; j_2)}. 
$$
Here $\beta_2^J(j_1,\; j_2)$ is a 2-cochain for $j_1, j_2, j_3 \in J$, and that 
$g_1=r(j_1)$, $g_2=r(j_2)$, $g_3=r(j_3) \in G$.

> question 1: For example, can we try explicitly that $G=\mathbb{Z}/2
> \mathbb{Z}=\mathbb{Z}_2$ the cyclic group, and $J=Q_8$ the quaternion
>   group. There are $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ types of group
>   morphism $r(j)=g$ of $J \overset{r}{\rightarrow} G$ as $Q_8 \overset{r}{\rightarrow} \mathbb{Z}_2$. If we know the 
>   explicit form of 3-cocycle of $G$, $\omega_3^{G}(g_1,g_2,g_3)    = 
> \exp \left( \frac{2 \pi i}{2^{2}} \;
> g_1(g_2 +g_3 -[(g_2 +g_3)\mod 2]) \right)$, how can we determine the analytic explicit form of 2-cochain $\beta_2^J(j_1,\; j_2)$ for the quaternion $J=Q_8$ such that it can trivialize the 3-cocycle of $G$ to 3-coboundary of $J$?
>
> **The key question for this post is asking the demonstration of this specific example: What is the explicit form of $\beta_2^{Q_8}(j_1,\; j_2)$?**

-

> question 2: Comments about the general procedure to trivialize
>   (split) 3-cocycle of $G$ to 3-coboundary of $J$, given that $J
>  \overset{r}{\rightarrow} G$. One can test that NOT all the $J$ with group homomorphism $J  \overset{r}{\rightarrow} G$ can trivialize $G$-cocycle. What conditions are necessary to find such $J$?

Any comments and partial answers are more than welcome, please!

Comment: You use multiplication by a complex number, multiplication and addition and addition mod $2$ in your cocycle, for elements of $G$ which is a priori only a group. Can you be clearer about the definition of the cocycle? Also, presumably you care more about the nontrivial $r$ than the trivial $r$, right?

Comment: Both the 3-cocycle and the 2-cochain are $U(1)=\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ complex functions with the norm=1. You can look for Borel group cohomology or [Dijkgraaf-Witten](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Dijkgraaf-Witten+theory) theory in the nLab. Yes, the nontrivial group homomorphism $r$, otherwise, the 3-cocycle $\omega^3(r(j_1),r(j_2),r(j_3))=1$ becomes a trivial 3-coboundary in the very boring way because $r(j)=$ identity element in $G$ (and it also works for any $J$ without additional conditions which are very trivial).

Comment: I add some new edits. Please shed some light on this.

Comment: The answer of question 2 should be that this is always possible. If i I am not wrong this was studied in the context of actions of finite groups on the hyperfinite type II1 factor. There is the notion of a $G$-kernel and they give a 3-cohomology class as invariant. To show that every cohomology class is realized one uses such an embedding into $J$. I have to check the reference and details myself. I think it can be found in the PhD thesis of Vaughan Jones.

Comment: @ Marcel Bischoff, thanks, but for question 2, I am more certain that NOT all the J is possible to trivialize the $G$-cocycle even if $J \to G$ has a group homomorphism. For example, I think that $J=\mathbb{Z}_6 \to G=\mathbb{Z}_2$ does NOT have a $J$ 2-cochain trivialize the $G$ 3-cocycle. There must be some additional conditions in addition to $J \to G$ has a group homomorphism. Something else is important.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an answer for question 2 on which homomorphisms $J\xrightarrow{r} \mathbb{Z}_2$ will trivialize $\omega_3^G$.

---

Your cocycle takes values in the two-element subgroup $\{1,-1\}\subset U(1)$ (aka $\{0,\frac{1}{2}\}\subset \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$). Since all two-element groups are isomorphic, you could of course identify this subgroup with $\mathbb{F}_2=\{0,1\}$ under addition. But why would you help? Well, $\mathbb{F}_2=\{0,1\}$ also has a *multiplication* (that's why I'm using a different letter for it), and so you can ask whether your cocycle factors as a **cup product** of two smaller cocycles. In this case, we'll see that it does! Let's see what happens in this case (this will also illustrate what a cup product is, if you're not familiar with this).

To start, we need to rewrite your formula
$$\omega_3^{G}(g_1,g_2,g_3)    = 
\exp \left( \frac{2 \pi i}{2^{2}} \;
g_1(g_2 +g_3 -[(g_2 +g_3)\mod 2]) \right)\in U(1)$$
to take values in $\mathbb{F}_2=\{0,1\}$. Note that the inputs $g_i$ in your formula live in $\mathbb{Z}_2=\{0,1\}$. What we get (for now) is
$$\omega_3(g_1,g_2,g_3)=g_1\cdot \frac{g_2 +g_3 -[(g_2 +g_3)\mod 2]}{2}\in \{0,1\}=\mathbb{F}_2.$$

The property we want to highlight is that this is a **product** of two simpler functions:

$$\omega_3(g_1,g_2,g_3)=\alpha(g_1)\cdot \beta(g_2,g_3)$$ where $$\alpha(g_1)=g_1\quad\text{ and }\quad\beta(g_2,g_3)=\frac{g_2 +g_3 -[(g_2 +g_3)\mod 2]}{2}.$$

---

What does this tell us? Well mathematically, we would write $r^*(\omega_3^G)\in H^2(J)$ for what you are calling $\omega_3^J$. And if $w_3\in H^3(\mathbb{Z}_2;\mathbb{F}_2)$ is the cohomology class represented by $\omega_3^G$, then $r^*(w_3)\in H^3(J;\mathbb{F}_2)$ is represented by $\omega_3^J$: so your question about trivializing the cocycle is whether $r^*(w_3)\overset{?}{=}0\in H^3(J;\mathbb{F}_2)$.

Note that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are both cocycles, so they represent cohomology classes $a\in H^1(\mathbb{Z}_2;\mathbb{F}_2)$ and $b\in H^2(\mathbb{Z}_2;\mathbb{F}_2)$. The factorization $$\omega_3(g_1,g_2,g_3)=\alpha(g_1)\cdot \beta(g_2,g_3)$$ then tells us that $w_3$ is the **cup product** of the cohomology classes $a$ and $b$: we have $w_3=a\cdot b$ (see my [answer here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/688/250) for details).

Cup product is an operation on cohomology that takes $x\in H^i$ and $y\in H^j$ and combines them to give $x\cdot y\in H^{i+j}$. It satisfies $y\cdot x = \pm x\cdot y$ where $\pm=(-1)^{ij}$.

---

The reason this is useful is that cup products are always preserved by $r^*$: there is a universal formula
$$r^*(x\cdot y)=r^*(x)\cdot r^*(y)\quad\text{in cohomology}.$$
This means that ONE way you could hope to show that $r^*(w_3)=0$ would be to show that either $r^*(a)=0$ or $r^*(b)=0$. Actually in 1st cohomology $r^*(a)$ will never be 0 unless the map $J\xrightarrow{r}\mathbb{Z}_2$ is trivial (an uninteresting case, as you discuss in comments), but you could hope that $r^*(b)=0$. [Side note: in your particular example in Q1, I checked and $r^*(b)\neq 0$.]

---

But actually there is a much better way to look at this. It comes from the fact that you wrote your cocycle in a way that hides its symmetry. I claim that if you work out the values of your cocycle $$\omega_3(g_1,g_2,g_3)=g_1\cdot \frac{g_2 +g_3 -[(g_2 +g_3)\mod 2]}{2}\in \{0,1\}=\mathbb{F}_2$$ on the 8 different possible inputs, you'll see that it can instead be written as 
$$\omega_3(g_1,g_2,g_3)=\begin{cases}1&\text{ if $g_1=1$, $g_2=1$, and $g_3=1$}\\0&\text{else}\end{cases}\in \{0,1\}=\mathbb{F}_2.$$
In other words, $$\omega_3(g_1,g_2,g_3)=g_1\cdot g_2\cdot g_3=\alpha(g_1)\cdot \alpha(g_2)\cdot \alpha(g_3).$$ This means that $w_3=a\cdot a \cdot a=a^3$. So not only can your cocycle be written in a simpler form, it actually is the cup product of a *single* class in 1st cohomology with itself three times.

Let us write $R\in H^1(J;\mathbb{F}_2)$ for $R=r^*(a)$. Then we have $r^*(w_3)=r^*(a)^3=R^3$, so the question of whether $r^*(w3)=0$ is simply the question of whether $R\in H^1(J;\mathbb{F}_2)$ satisfies
$$R^3=0\in H^3(J;\mathbb{F}_2).$$

Moreover, an element $R\in H^1(J;\mathbb{F}_2)$ is *equivalent* to a homomorphism $J\xrightarrow{r}\mathbb{Z}_2$ (that's why I used the same letter). So for a given $J$, your question is equivalent to finding all $R\in H^1(J;\mathbb{F}_2)$ satisfying $R^3=0$. Now, that's not going to necessarily be easy! But it is more likely to be something you can look up somehow. (And in some cases, you may be able to show that $R^2=0$, which would be enough.)

---

One last comment: you might be concerned that I was working with $\mathbb{F}_2$ coefficients here, whereas you had general $U(1)$ coefficients. Here is an argument why this is not so bad. Say we're given some class $z\in H^1$. If we take $x=z$ and $y=z$ in the formula $y\cdot x = \pm x\cdot y$ from above, it tells us $z\cdot z = - z\cdot z$. In other words, we always have $z^2+z^2=0\in H^2$. This means that if you have coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{Z}_3\subset U(1)$ or anywhere you can divide by 2, then $z^2$ would ALWAYS be 0 (and thus $z^3$ would be as well). This isn't quite a proof that you can always stick to $\mathbb{F}_2$ coefficients (for example, you might need to worry about $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}\subset U(1)$ as well) but as a general rule it argues that you can probably ignore factors other than $2$.

---

---

EDIT: Here is a concrete example of how to apply this to $Q_8$. According to (eq uation 2.4.2) of [this survey by Benson](http://library.msri.org/books/Book51/files/01benson.pdf), the cohomology ring of $Q_8$ is
$$H^*(Q_8;\mathbb{F}_2)\cong \mathbb{F}_2[x,y,z]/(\,x^2+xy+y^2,\,x^2y+xy^2\,)$$
where $x\in H^1$, $y\in H^1$, and $z\in H^4$.

Therefore $H^3(Q_8;\mathbb{F}_2)$ is spanned by the four elements $x^3$, $x^2y$, $xy^2$, and $y^3$ subject to the three relations $x^3+x^2y+xy^2=0$, $x^2y+xy^2+y^3=0$, and $x^2y+xy^2=0$. (The first two are $x(x^2+xy+y^2)$  and $y(x^2+xy+y^2)$.) Subtracting the last relation from the first two gives a basis of relations as $x^3=0$, $y^3=0$, and $x^2y+xy^2=0$.

You can now read off easily exactly which $R\in H^1(Q_8;\mathbb{F}_2)$ have $R^3=0$. Namely, if $R=x$ we have $R^3 = x^3 = 0$; if $R=y$ we have $R^3 = y^3 = 0$; and if $R=x+y$ we have $R^3 = (x+y)^3 = x^3 +3x^2y+3xy^2+y^3 = x^3 + (x^2y+xy^2) + y^3 = 0$. Therefore we conclude that *every* homomorphism $Q_8\to \mathbb{F}_2$ splits your cocycle!

---

You can do this for lots of other groups, if you can find where someone has already computed the $\mathbb{F}_2$-cohomology ring. For example, (eq. 2.8.1) of that same survey says that the "semidihedral group $SD_{2^n}$ of order $2^n$", whatever that is, has (for $n\geq 4$) the cohomology ring
$$H^*(SD_{2^n};\mathbb{F}_2)\cong \mathbb{F}_2[x,y,z,w]/(\,xy,\,y^3,\,yz,\,z^2+x^2w\,)$$
where $x\in H^1$, $y\in H^1$, $z\in H^3$, and $w\in H^4$. We find that $H^3(SD_{2^n};\mathbb{F}_2)$ is spanned by $x^3,x^2y,xy^2,y^3,z$ but with relations $x^2y=0$, $xy^2=0$, and $y^3=0$. Therefore we conclude that $R=x$ has $R^3=x^3\neq 0$ and $R=x+y$ has $R^3 = (x+y)^3 \equiv x^3 \neq 0$ but $R=y$ has $R^3=y^3=0$. So only one of the three nontrivial homomorphisms $SD_{2^n}\xrightarrow{r}\mathbb{Z}_2$ will split your cocycle.

---

Finally, you **only have to look at groups** $J$ **whose order is a power of 2**. This follows from a theorem of Cartan-Eilenberg, although it's a bit tricky to explain how (see Theorem 4.1 of [these lectures by Adem](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~bshipley/ConMcohomology1.pdf)). In any case, here is a precise statement you can use:

**Theorem**: Fix a homomorphism $J\xrightarrow{r}\mathbb{Z}_2$. For any subgroup $H<J$ whose order is a power of 2, you can consider the restriction $H\xrightarrow{r|_H}\mathbb{Z}_2$. Then the homomorphism $J\xrightarrow{r}\mathbb{Z}_2$ splits your cocycle $\iff$ for every subgroup $H<J$ whose order is a power of 2, the homomorphism $H\xrightarrow{r|_H}\mathbb{Z}_2$ splits your cocycle.

Answer (score 6):

A small remark first: I believe that the denominator in the exponent should be 2, and not $2^2$. 
In any case, write $Q_8=\langle x,y|x^2=y^2, xyx^{-1}=y^{-1},y^4=1\rangle$ so that each element in the group we can write uniquely as $y^ax^b$ with $a\in\{0,1,2,3\}$ and $b\in\{0,1\}$. 
By manipulating a bit the Lyndon Hochschild Serre spectral sequence, one gets the function $$\beta(y^ax^b,y^cx^d) = i^{bc}.$$ This function satisfies the desired property. 
Let me explain how to receive this $\beta$: Let us write $Q_8=G$, the normal subgroup as $N$ and the quotient group as $Q$. By choosing a set-theoretic lifting $s:Q\to G$, we can write each element of $G$ uniquely as a product $ns(q)$ for some $n\in N$ and $q\in Q$. Let us identify in this way $G$ with $N\times Q$ as a set. The key point here is that in the Lyndon Hochschild Serre spectral sequence you have a homomorphism $d_2:H^1(Q,H^1(N,U(1)))\to H^3(Q,U(1))$. Every element in the image of this $d_2$ will be in the kernel of the inflation map. In our case the group $H^1(Q,H^1(N,U(1)))$ is cyclic of order 2. It is generated by the map $f$ which sends the generator of $Q$ to the generator of the cyclic group of order 4, $H^1(N,U(1))$ (which sends a generator of $N$ to $i$). 
The idea now is that you try to cook up a two cocycle out of this element in the following way: $$\beta((n_1,q_1),(n_2,q_2)) = f(q_1^{-1})(n_2).$$
However, this $\beta$ might not be a two cocycle. The obstruction for this is of course $\partial \beta$. By a direct calculation, this is a three cocycle inflated from the quotient group $Q$, and this is exactly $d_2(f)$.

Comment: Also is that $\beta$ determined by the group homomorphism $r$, and something else? Can you see the generic pattern? Thanks.

Comment: You are right about the denominator, I wrote this expression in a different way, hence my mistake. I edited my answer and added some information.

Comment: Great. I think you may already answer the question 1 nicely. If you get a change, you can also try the question 2. You see that $J= \mathbb{Z}/6 \to G =\mathbb{Z}/2$ does NOT provide the desired 2-cochain, but that $J =Q_8 \to G= \mathbb{Z}/2$ does provide the desired 2-cochain. So in general, there must be some constraints on the choice of $J \to G$ or the $1 \to N \to J \to G \to 1$.

Comment: What you ask here is weather or not the inflation of the cocycle is trivial or not. This is a difficult question. The best answer I can give you is by using the Lyndon Hochschild Serre spectral sequence, and the argument I mentioned in the answer (you will also need to take into account $d_3$ though, not just $d_2$).For the case that $J=\mathbb{Z}/6$ the answer is actually quite easy due to one of the following two considerations: 1. The gcd of $|N|$ and $|Q|$ is 1, so the LHS spectral sequence collapses.2. the map $J\to \mathbb{Z}/2$ splits, and therefore the inflation map must be injective.

Comment: How do you see why one needs $f(q_1^{-1})$ instead of $f(q_1)$ in the 2-cochain?

Comment: To be honest this was mostly trial and error. There are many signs hanging around in these computations, and it is easy to make a mistake. I just calculated both and noticed that with $f(q_1^{-1})$ it works, and with the other one it doesn't.

Comment: @ Ehud Meir, an interesting answer. But it seems to me the answer is more like $i^{ad}$ for your 2-cochain.

Comment: both $i^{ad}$ and $i^{bc}$ would work here, I believe.

Comment: @Ehud Meir, could you answer this, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2046010, I tried to understand your argument, but using this example, I am not sure your method works.

Comment: @Ehud Meir, The [2-cochain for my question ](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2046010) based on your notation, should be $$\beta=(-1)^{(f(q_1^{-1}))_{Z2\times Z2} (n_2)_{Z_2}},$$ but I am not sure this works. I follow your notation. Thank you.

Comment: Actually I had trouble to understand your $\beta((n_1,q_1),(n_2,q_2)) = f(q_1^{-1})(n_2)$, should I just digest that as $$\beta((n_1,q_1),(n_2,q_2)) =\beta((y^{n_1} x^{q_1}),(y^{n_2} x^{q_2}))= f(q_1^{-1})(n_2)=i^{q_1n_2}?$$

Comment: But  then we can view $y^{n}$ for $n={0,1,2,3}$ as ${1,i,-1,-i}$ and $x^{q}$ for $q={0,1}$ as ${1,j}$. So in that case $f(q_1^{-1})$ sends $x$ to $y^2x$? Then I could not see how $\beta((n_1,q_1),(n_2,q_2)) = f(q_1^{-1})(n_2)=i^{q_1n_2}=i^{bc}$, can you illuminate through [2-cochain for my question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2046010), many thanks?

Comment: @Ehud Meir, Could you illuminate again $d_2(f)=d_2 \circ f$? It looks to me that
$$q \in Z_2  = Q \overset{f}{\longrightarrow} i \in H^1(N,U(1))=Z_4$$
and
$$H^1(Q,H^1(N,U(1)))=Z_2  \overset{d_2}{\longrightarrow} H^3(Q,U(1))=Z_2,$$
I am not certain how you combine the two functions to precisely determine $d_2 \circ f$? The image of $f$ is not the same as the domain of $d_2$, we must take care of that as well. Thanks.

Comment: The element $d_2(f)$ is not the same as the concatenation of functions $d_2\circ f$ which is not well defined, as you mentioned. The main question here is to calculate the differentials in the LHS spectral sequence, and this is in general a difficult thing to do. I do not know about a specific reference for that, I calculated some things myself.

Comment: @Ehud Meir, that is also my question to understand your answer; I think the differential $d$ is introduced in Kevin Knudson or Brown's book? You consider the $d_2$ to be:
$H^{d-2}(G/N, H^1(N,A))  \overset{d_2}{\longrightarrow}  H^{d}(G,A)?$
And you mentioned "may take into account $d_3$ though, not just $d_2$."
Is that $H^{d-3}(G/N, H^1(N,A))  \overset{d_3?}{\longrightarrow}  H^{d}(G,A)?$
in your mind? And why we need only $d_2$, not $d_3$ in our case? When will we need $d_3$. Many thanks.

Comment: Actually why do you intelligently choose to study $d_2$ to begin with?

Comment: As you said the differential $d_2$ is from the $E_2$ page of the spectral sequence, I suppose that the $d_3$ is from the $E_3$ page of the spectral sequence. How do you know wich one to choose? If we go to a higher $d$ of $H^d(G, U(1))$, does that the situation change?

Comment: you really do not need to touch the $E_3$ page at all. The reason for this is, as we said, that the entire $H^d(G,A)$ is contained in the image of $d_2$. This already ensures us that the inflation map is zero, even without considering what is happening in $E_3$, $E_4$ and so on

Comment: @Ehud Meir, Indeed, as he noticed, you said "you will also need to take into account $d_3$ though, not just $d_2$," when do we need to consider $d_3$? And is $d_3$ is also in $E_2$ page? If you can cite a Ref, I am happy and honored to read about this. It also depends on whether the $E_2$ page stabilizes $E_2=E_3=E_4= ...$ ?

Comment: @Ehud Meir and wonderich, I try to work through an example http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2046010  through your method, but I got $$\beta=(−1)^{ {(f(q_1))_{Z_2 \times Z_2}} (n_2)_{Z_2}}$$ but I could NOT get $\omega_3=\delta \beta_2$ correct, does that mean your method need to be modified or something is subtle?

Comment: @Ehud Meir, May I just ask please: Is this approach you describe by finding such 2-cochain, $$\beta((n_1,q_1),(n_2,q_2)) = f(q_1^{-1})(n_2)$$ works for trivializing any 3-cocycle of $Q$ through any $$1 \to N \to G\to Q \to 1 ???$$  What is the limitation of your argument? It seems pretty general (from the $d_2$ property in $E_2$)? When will your method seize to work?

Comment: The formula above is just $\partial\beta=\partial_2 f$. The first $\partial$ is for the differential of cochains, the second one of the spectral sequence. You are interested in the kernel of the inflation map. By general spectral sequence arguments, this is generated by the image of $\partial_2$ and the image of $\partial_3$ of the subgroup of $H^2(N,H^0(Q,M))$ living in $E_3$. So you cannot automatically trivialize any 3-cocycle, but you know what is the kernel of the inflation map. See also: http://mathoverflow.net/q/250287/41644 .

Comment: This is getting into the key. Will you be able to use your method to determine this too: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/256763 ?

Comment: Is that $H^1(Q,H^1(N,U(1)))=H^1(\mathbb{Z}_4,H^1(\mathbb{Z}_2,U(1)))=H^1(\mathbb{Z}_4,\mathbb{Z}_2)=\mathbb{Z}_2$? @Ehud Meir, thanks!