# Trivialize a cup-product 3-cocycle of $G$ in a larger group $J$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gr.group-theory, homological-algebra, group-cohomology, spectral-sequences

Inspired by [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/250287/g-cocycle-split-to-a-coboundary-in-j-via-a-group-extension), let us take a nontrivial 3-cocycle $\omega_3^G(g_a, g_b, g_c) \in H^3(G,\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})$ in the cohomology group of $G$ with $U(1)=\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ coefficient. In otherwords, here the 3-cocycle $\omega_3^G$ is a complex $U(1)=\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ function with the norm $|\omega_3^G|=1$ but with a $U(1)$ complex phase satisfying the cocycle condition. Here $g_a, g_b, g_c \in G$.

We like to ask how can we trivialize  the 3-cocycle $\omega_3(g_a, g_b, g_c)$ of $G$ into 3-coboundary if we lift $G$ into a larger group $J$, and given that we know the group homomorphism $r$:

> $$J \overset{r}{\rightarrow} G,$$

so that
$$\omega_3^J(j_a, j_b, j_c)=\omega_3^G(r(j_a),r(j_b),r(j_c))=\omega_3^G(g_a, g_b, g_c) \text{ is trivial in  }  H^3(J,\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}).$$

I like to take $G=\mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$, and consider the group element $g_a=(g_{a1}, g_{a2}, g_{a3}) \in (\mathbb{Z}_2, \mathbb{Z}_2, \mathbb{Z}_2)=\mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2 =G$, similarly, $g_b=(g_{b1},g_{b2},g_{b3}) \in G$ and $g_{c}=(g_{c1},g_{c2},g_{c3}) \in G$. Let me focus on the 3-cocycle

> $$
> \omega_3^G(g_a, g_b, g_c)=\exp[i \pi \cdot g_{a1} \cdot g_{b2} \cdot g_{c3}]=(-1)^{g_{a1} \cdot g_{b2} \cdot g_{c3}} \in  H^3(G,\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}),
> $$
>   is in a cup product form of $g_a, g_b, g_c$.

Here $\cdot$ is a usual product of multiplication. And $g_{a1} \cdot g_{b2} \cdot g_{c3} \in \{0,1\}= \mathbb{Z}_2$.

We wish to find that $\omega_3^G(r(j_a),r(j_b),r(j_c))$ becomes a 3-coboundary in $H^3(J,\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})$ for the cohomology group of $J$, but $\omega_3^G(g_a,g_b,g_c)$ originally was not a 3-coboundary but was a 3-cocycle for the cohomology group of $G$. We hope to explicitly write 
$$
\omega_3^G(g_a,g_b,g_c)=\omega_3^G(r(j_a),r(j_b),r(j_c))=
\frac{\beta_2^J(j_b,\; j_c)\beta_2^J(j_a,\; j_b  j_c)}{\beta_2^J(j_a   j_b,\; j_c) \beta_2^J(j_a,\; j_b)}. 
$$
Here $\beta_2^J(j_a,\; j_b)$ is a 2-cochain for $j_a, j_b, j_c \in J$, and that 
$g_a=r(j_a)$, $g_b=r(j_b)$, $g_c=r(j_c) \in G$.

> **Question:** For example, can we find explicitly what is the minimal $J$, so we can trivialize a cup-product 3-cocycle $(-1)^{g_{a1} \cdot g_{b2} \cdot g_{c3}}$ of $G=\mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$ in a larger group $J$? Here $G$ is order 8 group. Perhaps $J$ is a group of order 16 at least?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The group $J$ has to be of order divisible by 16, due to the fact that if the order of the group $J$ is $8n$ where $n$ is an odd number, then the inflation of the cocycle will not be trivial (for example due to the fact that the quotient map $r:J\to G$ will split).

There is no one minimal $J$. The reason for this is the following: You can consider your cocycle in the following way: on $\mathbb{Z}_2$ take the nontrivial element $c$ in $H^1(\mathbb{Z}_2,\mathbb{Z}_2)$, lift to to $G$ three times (each time use a different copy of $\mathbb{Z}_2$), and denote the results by $c_1, c_2$ and $c_3$. Take the cup product $c_1c_2c_3\in H^3(G,\mathbb{Z}_2)$ and apply the natural embedding of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ in $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$. In this way you get your cocycle $\omega$. Now, if you consider the cocycle $c_1c_2\in H^2(\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2,\mathbb{Z}_2)$ This corresponds to an extension of the form $$1\to \mathbb{Z}_2\to D_8\to \mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2\to 1,$$ and the inflation of $c_1c_2$ to $D_8$ is then trivial. For that reason, the map $D_8\times \mathbb{Z}_2\to G$ trivializes the cocycle. Of course that you could have chosen $\mathbb{Z}_2\times D_8$, with the cocycle $c_2c_3$ instead. This also gives us a concrete way to construct $\beta$: After following the trivialization to $c_1c_2$ arising from the above extension and by writing elements in $D_8$ as triples $(x,y,z)$ with $x,y,z\in\mathbb{Z}_2$ (so that the multiplication is given by $$(x_1,y_1,z_1)(x_2,y_2,z_2) = (x_1+x_2+y_1z_2,y_1+y_2,z_1+z_2),$$
we end up with the formula $$\beta(((x_1,y_1,z_1),w_1)),((x_2,y_2,z_2),w_2)) = (-1)^{x_1w_2}$$

Comment: The fact about trivialization of 2 cocycles in the relevant extension can be found in most textbooks on cohomology of groups or even of homological algebra. The suggested solution will be of the form $$1\to Z_2\to D_8\times Z_2\to Z_2^3\to 1.$$

Comment: What book/papers do you recommend me the most for this context? Thank you.

Comment: you are welcome :)
I think that in Cohomology of groups of Brown, or in Homological algebra by Rotman or Homological algebra of Weibel you will some good answers

Comment: Thanks, What about the continuous group, :), http://mathoverflow.net/questions/253887, any idea? (p.s. I will accept your answer in a few days if no one gives other better reply.)

Comment: Does this work if we replace dihedral $D_8$ to quaternion $H_8$?

Comment: Two questions: (1) Is your $\beta_2$ a nontrivial element in $H^2(D_8 \times Z_2, R/Z)$? (2) Does this work if we replace dihedral $D_8$ to quaternion $H_8$?

Comment: @Ehud Meir, Your answer is nice. Actually, just for my own curiosity, I don't see $\beta(((x_1,y_1,z_1),w_1)),((x_2,y_2,z_2),w_2)) = (-1)^{x_1w_2}$ really work. And I checked myself, I kind of doubt it works for trivialization -- perhaps you had typos or error.

Comment: @Ehud Meir, even if we define $D_8 \times Z_2 \overset{r}{\to} (Z_2)^3$ by the map $r$, and revise the 2-cochain to  
$$\beta((h_1,w_1)),(h_2,w_2)) = (-1)^{x_1 r(h_2,w_2)},$$
 this seems not work out either. Here we denote $h_1=(x_1,y_1,z_1) \in D_8$ and $h_2=(x_2,y_2,z_2)  \in D_8$. Here $r(h_2,w_2)$ is defined through the map $D_8 \times Z_2 \overset{r}{\to} (Z_2)^3$.

Comment: Neither  $(-1)^{x_2 r(h_1,w_1)}$, nor $(i)^{x_1 r(h_2,w_2)}$, nor $(i)^{x_2 r(h_1, w_1)}$ work -- none of these work out, surprisingly.

Comment: It seems to me that the trivialization of $c_1c_2\in H^2(\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2,\mathbb{Z}_2)$ or $c_1c_2\in H^2(\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2,R/Z)$  through an extension of the form $$1\to \mathbb{Z}_2\to D_8\to \mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2\to 1,$$ using $(-1)^{x_1}$ may also be incorrect. Not sure if I made a mistake or not. Does $D_8$ really work or do we need quaternion $H_8$?

Comment: Your answer puzzles me because it seems not really work. I ask a simpler question hopefully you can clarify: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/256161/

Comment: I checked it again, it really seems to work. I enclose the calculation here, please point out if you find a mistake:
I write $((x_a,y_a,b_a),w_a)=j_a$, and similarly for $b$ and $c$. I then get: $$\beta(j_a,j_b) = (-1)^{x_aw_b}. \beta(j_aj_b,j_c) = (-1)^{(x_a+x_b+y_az_b)w_c},$$ $$\beta(j_b,j_c)= (-1)^{x_bw_c}. \beta(j_a,j_bj_c) = (-1)^{x_a(w_b+w_c)}.$$ By calculating now the relevant quotient I get $(-1)^{y_az_bw_c}$, which is exactly the inflation of $\beta$. Since $\partial\beta$ is not 1, $\beta$ is not a two cocycle. I am really not sure about the quaternion group.

Comment: @Ehud Meir, I write an answer for this question, not sure whether you can take a look and see the math structure of the cochain solutions --- and illuminate how this works? http://mathoverflow.net/questions/256161/

Comment: @Ehud Meir, do you see that your example $D_8 \to (\mathbb{Z}_2)^2$also works for split all the 3-cocycles in $$\omega_3\in H^3(\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2, \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})?$$
For example, the cup-product of $a1 \cup a2 \cup a2$, and also $a1 \cup a1 \cup a1$?

Comment: it will trivialize $a_1\cup a_2$, and therefore everything that is divisible by $a_1\cup a_2$, for the same reason as above ($a_1\cup a_2$ is the two cocycle which corresponds to the extension). About $a_1^3$ or $a_2^3$: it will not split. One can prove this directly, by using the fact that the extension above is trivial when restricted to the two cyclic subgroups.

Comment: @ Ehud Meir, I found a strange fact, would you illuminate. I found that $$1 \to Z_2 \to Q_8  \to (Z_2)^2 \to 1$$ can [split the 2-cocycle of the cup-product form](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/256161) $a_1 \cup a_2$ as $\omega_2 \in H^2((Z_2)^2, R/Z)$. But I could not find any, say that
$1 \to Z_2 \to Q_8  \to (Z_2)^2 \to 1$ cannot split the 3-cocycle of the cup-product form $a_1 \cup a_2 \cup a_2$ as $\omega_3 \in H^3((Z_2)^2, R/Z)$. Thanks.

Comment: Thus, it seems that [the question here  by miss-tery](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/256763) could be negative: Do you know why?

Comment: Is your statement "if it trivializes a1∪a2, and therefore it trivializes everything that is divisible by a1∪a2, e.g. a1∪a2∪a2," still holds?

Comment: I stand behind it. If you have a group homomorphism $\phi:G\to H$, then then induced map in cohomology $\phi^*:H^*(H,M)\to H^*(G,M)$ is a ring homomorphism. Therefore, if $a_1\cup a_2$ is in the kernel, so is $a_1\cup a_2\cup a_2$.

Comment: @Ehud Meir. Thanks very much. Sorry I am slow. What is your $G$ and $H$ groups in the examples of $1 \to Z_2 \to Q_8 \to (Z_2)^2  \to 1$? And what is the ${}^*$ here? Do you mean that $\phi^∗: H^∗(H,M)\to H^∗(G,M)$ as $\phi^3: H^3(H,U(1))\to H^3(G,U(1))$ with $M=U(1)$?

Comment: no worries :) the $G$ and $H$ are $Q_8$ and $(Z_2)^2$, and the map $\phi$ is just the quotient map.

Comment: @Ehud Meir, Great! Thanks. But what is the ${}^∗$ here? Do you mean that $ϕ^∗:H^∗(H,M)→H^∗(G,M)$ as $ϕ^3:H^3(H,U(1))→H^3(G,U(1))$ with $M=U(1)$?

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49901/discussion-between-wonderich-and-ehud-meir).

Comment: @Ehud Meir: 

If your claim is correct, then based on my anwser in http://mathoverflow.net/questions/256161/ for 1→Z2→Q8→(Z2)^2→1 split 1-cochain for H^2(Z2^2,U(1)), and your argument, there should be an answer for miss-tery's question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/256763/ for 1→Z2→Q8→(Z2)^2→1 split 2-cochain for H^3(Z2^2,U(1)). But I could not find it.... Something is weird...