# Trivialize a cocycle of a continuous Lie group-cohomology to a coboundary

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gr.group-theory, lie-groups, group-cohomology, spectral-sequences

Someone recently asks a question [$SO(3)$ 2-cocycle trivialized to a 2-coboundary in $SU(2)$?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/253887/) now inspires me to revisit an earlier general [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/250287/g-cocycle-split-to-a-coboundary-in-j-via-a-group-extension/250397#250397) to ask an example of 3-cocycle 
$\omega_3^G$ of a cohomology group $H^3[G,\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}]$ for the case when **$G$ is a continuous group, say $G=U(1)=SO(2)$**, instead of a finite group.

We already know that:

> $$\omega_3^G \in H^3[G,\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}]=\mathbb{Z}$$

Consider a $3$-cocycle $\omega_3^G \in H^3(U(1),\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}$ in the cohomology group of a group $G$ with $U(1)=\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ coefficient. There are $\mathbb{Z}$ classes of $\omega_3^G$.

> **Question**: We ask **whether there exists some group $N$ as a normal subgroup** of some bigger group $J$, such that $G$ is the quotient group
>   $$
> \frac{J}{N}=G
> $$
>   and **such that we can always trivialize the $3$-cocycle $\omega_3^G$ of $G=U(1)$ into $3$-coboundary if we lift $G$ into a larger group $J$**? Given that we know the group homomorphism $r$:
>   $$J \overset{r}{\rightarrow} G.$$
>   Namely,
>   $$
> \omega_3^G(g_i,\dots)=\omega_3^G(r(j_i),\dots)=
> \delta \beta_{2}^J(j_i,\dots). 
> $$
>   with $g \in G, j \in J$. Here $\beta_{2}^J$ is a 2-cochain of $J$.
>
> **Guess: I am guessing that we may not be able to find such a $J$ to trivialize the 3-cocycle of $G=U(1)$. How can we verify or prove this?**